# Javascript - functions depending on the results of other functions

Tags: javascript, css, function, loops

Im writing some utility JS libraries with some common code that is used in front end web development - stuff for filling the gaps that plain CSS cant, when we need certain pixel perfect things that designers want

I have a collection of functions that run on page init as well as resize and other events, each that does a certain thing, for example matches the heights of a bunch of elements, stuff like that. Each function will most likely contain some kind of loop that loops through a collection of elements and updates some CSS styles.

My issue is this - what if some of the actions in one of these functions depends on one of the OTHER functions running first? I cant handle this naively by just reordering the function calls, because as this utils library grows there may end up being a LOT of different functions that are called.

Also, not all the iterations of the loop in each function will always need to wait for another functions loop to complete - sometimes it wont matter.

Im not sure if Im explaining this well, heres some psuedocode

```
function matchHeights(){
   for(item in items){
      //do CSS stuff to each item
   }
}

function verticalCenter(){
   for(item in items){
      //do CSS stuff each item
   }
}
```

as you can see both `matchHeights()` and `verticalCenter()` contain a loop that loops through a bunch of items and does some JS to each one to apply the desired CSS to each item.

But what if *some* of the items in the `verticalCenter()` loop are nested in the DOM inside some of the items that are in the `matchHeights()` loop? The relevant parent items would need to have `matchHeights()` called on them first, before their child items had `verticalCenter()` called, otherwise the child elements would not be correctly vertically centered to the new heights set for the parents by `matchHeights()`

Obviously in that case, calling `verticalCenter()` *after* `matchHeights()` would solve it, but I hope this demonstrates how there could be issues like this that cant be solved by simply reordering the function call.

I'm thinking what I need is some kind of "master" loop that has a sequence of events where it calls specific functions on each item in the right order, instead of each function just looping through all the items blindly, but Im not sure how best to structure this.

If any of my blathering makes sense, some advice would be appreciated :)

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that some of your internal library functions have dependencies on other functions in the same utility library in order to run? You could architect it in such a way that you can provide a single element or multiple elements to a given utility function. Build this around promises and you'll have something similar to JQuery.

Comment: use the same approach that built in to javascript - define metohds for window object, then use them as `window.afterLoad('element_id') { //foo}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is quite vague the code that you displayed, but I'll elaborate my thoughts on what I understand.

You have several items you need to pass through several functions, so don't trust each loop by itself.

Have a "manager" that will know what each item should have, like:

```
var items = [
     {item: "whatever", matchHeights: true, verticalCenter: true},
     {item: "whatever", verticalCenter: true},
     {item: "whatever", matchHeights: true}
];
```

and now your "manager" will loop the items array, and will check what methods it needs to run on each item.

Of course if it's more complex, you give it priority, counts etc.

Comment: Ye it seems like i will need some kind of queue/register of functions to run

Comment: I don't really know what is your complexity, but I think this is the way to go on that situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of callback as shown below. You need to implement it in a plugin style. You can use some logic when to trigger the matchheight is completely applied to the elements you need.

```
$('div').matchHeight({
   onComplete: function(){
      $('another-div').verticalHeight();
   }
});
```